# C++ Trie using std::map and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, hash-map, trie

I'm learning C++ and whilst trying to write in **modern** C++, I've made an attempt to rewrite a trie implementation written in C found here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

It uses arrays to hold the branches in each node and because it's C it was done using malloc() and no freeing of memory was done in the example.

Is this an efficient approach of representing a trie in C++11? what other ways can I store children in trie nodes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

class Trie {
    struct Node;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Node> spNode;
    struct Node {
        std::map<char, spNode> children;
        bool isLeaf;
        Node() : isLeaf{false} {}
    };

    spNode root;
public:
    Trie();
    void insert(const std::string& str);
    bool search(const std::string& str);
};

Trie::Trie():root{nullptr}{}

void Trie::insert(const std::string& str) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        std::unique_ptr<Node> node(new Node());
        root = std::move(node);
    }

    Node *temp = root.get();
    for (const char& c : str) {
        if (temp->children.find(c) == temp->children.end()) {//if char not in map
            std::unique_ptr<Node> node(new Node());
            temp->children[c] = std::move(node);
        }

        temp = temp->children[c].get();
    }

    temp->isLeaf = true;
}

bool Trie::search(const std::string &str) {
    if (root == nullptr) return false;

    Node *temp = root.get();
    for (const char& c : str) {
        if (temp->children.find(c) == temp->children.end())
            return false;
        temp = temp->children[c].get();
    }
    return (temp->isLeaf);
}

int main (void) {
    std::string words[] = { "Hello", "hi", "hey", "howdy", "ho"};
    Trie test;

    for (const auto& str : words) {
        test.insert(str);
    }


   if (test.search("Hello"))
       std::cout << " 'Hello' is found in the trie\n";
    else
       std::cout <<" 'Hello' is not found in the trie\n";

   if (test.search("yo"))
       std::cout << " 'yo' is found in the trie\n";
    else
       std::cout << " 'yo' is not found in the trie\n";


}
```

Comment: No `hash-map` here. `std::map` has the same characteristics as a tree. `std::unordered_map` is closer to  a `hash-map` but I believe has a much larger space requirements.

Comment: You aren't quite consistent in deciding whether to enclose a single-statement-body in braces...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see the need for `unique_ptr` for the root node.

```
spNode root;
```

I would just make this a node.

```
Node root;
```

The use of `std::map` is fine. But it does have `O(log(n))` lookup. If you switch back to an array its `O(1)`. Its a time for space thing. Pick the one you want.

I don't like the two line creation of nodes.

```
        std::unique_ptr<Node> node(new Node());
        temp->children[c] = std::move(node);
```

Just use reset:

```
        temp->children[c].reset(new Node());
```

Or if you have C++14 use `std::make_unique()`

```
        temp->children[c] = std::make_unique<Node>();
```

Personally `search()` does not seem quite the correct verb.

```
bool search(const std::string& str);
```

What is wrong with `find()`?

Comment: `std::make_unique()` is available in C++14 as well, unless I am missing something obvious (I often do)!

Comment: @user2296177, make unique is introduced in C++14, if you meant that C++11 has it as well.

Answer (score 3):

@LokiAstari hit pretty much all the points I'd have made, but I'd like to expand on one point and then make one philosophical point:

---

> The use of `std::map` is fine. But it does have `O(log(n))` lookup.

`std::map` is the C++ equivalent of Java's TreeMap. It's *big* (it stores about three pointers per node) and *slow* (lookups require following `log(n)` of those pointers on average, and inserts can require rebalancing of the [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), thus touching even more pointers) and therefore *cache-unfriendly* (a single tree lookup can dirty up to `log(n)` cache lines, none of which will be helpful for the next tree lookup) and therefore *even slower*.

And you're not just using *one* `std::map` — you're using one `std::map` *per node in your trie*, i.e., you're making a big pointer-based tree *of* big pointer-based trees. This is just absolutely awful for performance.

So yes, an array `spNode *children[256]` would probably be preferable. Or it might be worth the effort to abstract out a data type like

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct FastMapForTries {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Key, char>, "Key type must be char");
    Value favorite_children['z' - 'A' + 1];
    std::map<Key, Value> other_children;
    Value& operator[](const Key& k) const { ... }
};
```

just to reduce the size of a `Trie::Node` from `257*8` back down to `59*8 + sizeof(std::map)`.

---

If you're sticking with the `std::map`, then at least you should avoid looking things up in the map repeatedly.

```
    if (temp->children.find(c) == temp->children.end()) {//if char not in map
        std::unique_ptr<Node> node(new Node());
        temp->children[c] = std::move(node);
    }

    temp = temp->children[c].get();
```

I count *three* tree lookups in this short snippet. Try this instead:

```
    auto it = temp->children.find(c);
    if (it == temp->children.end()) {  // if char not in map
        it = temp->children.emplace_hint(it, c, std::make_unique<Node>());
    }
    temp = it;
```

Now there's only two lookups. — You might say "only one lookup", but look again and notice (as I missed the first time I wrote this code) that [`emplace_hint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint) is only ever called with `end()` as the hint! So using `emplace_hint` here is exactly as inefficient as using unhinted `emplace`. A really good static analysis tool might have caught this bug of mine.

So let's do this instead:

```
    auto pair = temp->children.insert(c, nullptr);
    temp = pair.first;
    if (pair.second) {  // if we just inserted nullptr
        *temp = std::make_unique<Node>();
    }
```

Now there's only one tree lookup!  If you have benchmarks for your trie code, you should see a ~3x speedup from just this one little refactor.

---

@Loki mentioned your awkwardly named `trie.search(word)` method; he suggested `trie.find(word)`. But I'd say that `find` isn't the right word either. `find` in the STL denotes "look for and return an iterator to", and (right now) your trie doesn't have iterators. So right now, the most STL-ish name for your method is `trie.count(word)`, and it should return `0` or `1`.

Of course if you're not going for absolute STL-ish-ness, `bool trie.contains(word)` would be the most user-friendly name.

But here's the philosophical point: When designing a data structure, you should treat observations such as "`find` is the wrong name because `find` returns an iterator" as questions to be seriously considered and responded to!

- I'd like to use the name `find`...
- But `find` needs to return an iterator...
- Is my trie iterable? No. *Can* one iterate a trie?...
- Yes, I suppose so (if we introduce parent pointers). An iterator would naturally look like a *pointer* to a leaf of the trie. Should I make my trie iterable?...
- Hmm. What else can one do with a pointer to a leaf of the trie? What operations are [afforded by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance) a pointer-to-leaf?...
- How about fast insertion of a suffix? For example, if I had a pointer to the last character of `"dog"`, I could quickly append a child-leaf to make `"dogs"`.
- Huh! That sounds a lot like the `emplace_hint` method we were just using!
- What about a [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) method to go along with it?

...and suddenly we're inventing a rich and useful data structure that wasn't even on our radar at the beginning of the conversation. So, always take API-design questions seriously! :)

Comment: I love your workaround with the insert

Comment: **"you're not just using one std::map — you're using one std::map per node in your trie"**  - I'd imagine using the `std::unordered_map` would be more appropriate?

Comment: @Cyniscus: Nope. That would just make me say "you're using one std::unordered_map per node in your trie" — which is still a ridiculous amount of overhead. A big pointer-based tree of pointer-based hashmaps is only slightly less silly than a big pointer-based tree of pointer-based trees.